# Derived classes with ActiveRecord in Yii

Tags: inheritance, activerecord, yii

I am working with the following database design, and wanted to understand how we can best address it in Yii.

```
+---------------+----------------+---------------------+
|     Table     |  Column name   |     Column Type     |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------+
| question      | id             | int                 |
|               | description    | text                |
|               | type           | ENUM('mcq', 'text') |
|               |                |                     |
|               |                |                     |
| mcq_question  | id             | int                 |
|               | question_id    | int                 |
|               | option1        | text                |
|               | option2        | text                |
|               | option3        | text                |
|               | option4        | text                |
|               | correct_answer | option1             |
|               |                |                     |
|               |                |                     |
| text_question | id             | int                 |
|               | question_id    | int                 |
|               | answer         | text                |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

The idea is to have different kind of questions like mcq, text, grid, true/false etc. Their common data can be captured in the "question" table, while the specifics can be captured in the respective tables. In simple programming concepts, it is easy to map this structure to a "Question" class which is the base class for all other classes like "MCQ_Question", "Text_Question" etc. The types of such questions may increase in future, hence the need for flexibility.

With the above approach, I can use the "question_id" for any foreign key relationships with other tables, rather than working with each individual table, which would make the code more complex.

From what I understood by reading some of the articles, this approach doesn't work with Yii:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23405-cactiverecord-inheritance-and-dynamic-attributes/

Is there no way to do it with Yii? If not, then what could be some of the workarounds for this problem which would keep the code simple.

Regards,
Kapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you refer to does not apply to your question. You can just create the derived classes and override the `tableName()`-function so that they load out of the correct table.

First of all, in this situation I would not use different IDs for the derived types, just use the same ID. One question_id for all is a lot easier to maintain (and store answers for). Just remove the auto_increment from the derived tables id field and remove question_id. Assuming you do that:

A minimalised example for MCQ_Question:

```
class MCQ_Question extends Question
{
   public $description = '';
   public $type = 'mcq';

   function tableName()
   {
      return 'mcq_question';
   }
}
```

There are now only 2 issues remaining:
1) A generic function in the base class that loads a specific question
2) If you save the derived class, it should also update/create the question instance

1) This is fairly easy, but you might have to add an array to "convert" between the enum and a class name:

```
class Question extends CActiveRecord
{
   public function findById($questionId)
   {
      $types = array('mcq' => 'MCQ_Question');
      $question = $this->findByPk($questionId);
      if ($question && array_key_exists($question->type, $types)
      {
         $class = $types[$question->type];
         return $class::model()->findByPk($question->id);
      }
   }
}
```

The array with the links is not the most graceful solution, but it does the trick. You can also add it as a static so it's more clear it would have to be updated, and so on.

2) You can accomplish this by overriding the `beforeSave()`-function in the derived classes.

```
  public function beforeSave()
  {
     if ($this->isNewRecord)
     {
        $question = new Question();
        $question->type = $this->type;
        $question->description = $this->description;
        $question->save();
        $this->id = $question->id;
     }
     // else check if perhaps the description was changed and update it
    ...
```

This is obviously not all the code you need but then again, it's not my job to do yours ;)

It should get you started though. The beforeSave would probably end up pretty much the same everywhere so if your PHP is recent enough, you could do this in a `trait`.

Comment: Hi Blizz,

Thanks for the fantastic explanation. Your approach is very logical, and I think it should do the trick. As you said, using "traits" should also help me reduce the redundant code.

The only think which bothered me slightly is that if any column gets modified/added in the "base class", then all the derived classes also need to be updated, but I guess there's no way out for that. 

Thanks again for your guidance !

Regards,
Kapil

Comment: You're very welcome. You could overcome the changed column issue by creating a new Question instance yourself, saving it and then passing that as an attribute to your derived class. beforeSave would just have to copy the $id then and that's it. Just an idea. After all, it's not that you will be creating questions on tons of places in your code.